# Can we change the frame rate for a video to 24 after the image sequence is rendered with a different fps, say 30?

Tags: rendering

I have rendered an image sequence from my animation, with FPS 30. Now, while making the video from that particular image sequence, can I use a different FPS, say 24 ?

Technically it is possible, I have checked with a small test video. But my doubt is, **does it make any difference in the video quality inherently ?**

Let me assume that the answer to the above question is NO (which also seems logical to me since each png file is complete on its own and they can be viewed at any speed). But then the question that comes to my mind is, why do we have the frame rate settings at all while rendering as an image sequence ? It seems more logical to display frame rate settings only during the video rendering, and disable it during image rendering since it remains meaningless in that case. Or is there any other purpose of setting the frame rate during the image render ?

I have checked some similar questions on this topic but did not get a complete answer to my original question + the doubt above. Hence I am posting it as a new question. Any suggestion from experts will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge using another frame rate while rendering an image sequence will ,without changing anything else, change the quality of the output video because a different number of the images out of the sequence will be shown in the output video per second. But the other more noticeable effect would be that by packing a different number of frames in each second you would effectively **speed up/ slow down** the output video.

It is possible to correct for that speed up in the strip options under time, but you run into another issue: While the video is paused it makes no difference in quality, but if the rendered frame rate of the image sequence is not a multiple of the the new frame rate it can lead to glittery motion. This happens because blender sometimes would need frames that lay between the given frames in the images sequence. Because that is not possible it has to decide for one of those frames. The distance between the chosen frames can vary, sometimes be 1, sometimes be 2, so in the rendered video the motion seems to jump.

so most of the time it makes sense to stick to one frame rate from start to finish.

For why the frame rate needs to be able to be changed even if you render an Image Sequence:
One simple reason is that the viewport animation works with the same frame rate so to change that you need that option exposed.

Does that answer your questions?
I hope my explanation makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer. Did you make a typo in your first sentence where you wanted to say that there won't be any change in quality ? I am not sure. Anyway, I think you correctly pointed out that the video will speed up/ slow down, which is obvious... but I was referring to the display quality. I understood your answer. I will accept it if no better or no more detailed answer is posted. Thanks once again for helping me out. You are awesome!

Comment: If all you are refering to with quality is the quality of the images then yes, the quality doesnt change. But the quality of the final video **will** change, because there are more factors to video quality than singe image quality. Thats what i mean in the first sentence. I hope that makes things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The fps in image sequence rendering is perfectly reasonable: it tells blender how many frames to be rendered in every single second of the animations. The speed of the animation is sothing you can control, but you won't change it after you choose an initial setting.

Let's take into consideration a video of a man that walks:
2 steps should last 1 seconds: if you render 100 fps and 1 second of animation (100 images) you'll have 1 step.

If you later change the fps (let's say 30 fps), you'll have again the same 1 step, but with a less smooth frame rate.

Comment: Some reference in changing the frame rate of a video with ffmpeg: https://superuser.com/questions/843292/ffmpeg-how-does-ffmpeg-decide-which-frames-to-pick-when-fps-value-is-specified/843363#843363 https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ChangingFrameRate

Comment: When we render a scene in Blender, we explicitly mention the start frame number and end frame number, effectively telling Blender how many frames to be generated. We don't enter length of the output in seconds. So FPS makes no sense here (for image sequence output). Had it been the case that we mention the length of the animation for image sequence output, FPS would have been meaningful and mandatory. But we mention exact number of frames to be generated. So, I am still not sure what purpose is being met by entering FPS in image sequence output.

Answer (score 0):

An image sequence is just a collection of consecutive images, each image being a still frame. FPS only matters for playback and for videos. Since Blender can play animations no matter if "live" in viewport or from rendered video or image sequence, this information is used for playback. (I guess that's why you find it in the *Dimensions* settings rather than the *Output* settings.)

In a video file, the framerate determines what speed is "normal" to play the video. Still images are not tied to a certain framerate. So if you render an image sequence with let's say 240 frames at 30 fps, then this would be 8 seconds if you play it at 30 fps.

But it's simply 240 frames. If you make a video out of it with 24 fps, the video will last 10 seconds. That's how my digital camera makes slow-motion videos. It records at 120 fps but puts them into a video file set to 30 fps - this makes the footage look like 4 times slower. If I make an image sequence out of the individual frames and make a 120 fps video out of it, the speed of the footage would look absolutely normal.

The only problem you might experience is that your animation will be a bit slower than you expect/need it to be, if you stretch those 8 to 10 seconds. If you want to keep it at 8 seconds, you have to scale the sequence in the *Video Editor* or cut out single frames to reduce the 240 to 192 frames. In both cases I suspect the animation wouldn't look as smooth as before.

Comment: Thanks! This perfectly explains the result of FPS change. Yes, changing the FPS during video render will make the video faster or slower. However, my doubt was, why there is a frame-rate setting when rendering an image sequence. FPS makes no sense when all we want is a bunch of still images, and we explicitly also mention the start frame number and end frame number, effectively telling Blender how many frames to be generated. We don't enter length of the output in seconds. So FPS makes no sense here (for image sequence output). Or maybe I am still missing something.

Comment: As I said in my first paragraph, there might be a reason why you find the FPS setting in the _Dimensions_ settings and _not_ in the _Output_ settings. They are used for playback and preview and Blender uses them to play the animated image sequence after you rendered it if you hit Ctrl + 11. Let's say you're making a movie at 24 fps. If you animated a character too fast or slow to look right at 24 fps, changing playback in Blender won't help your movie - and dropping or stretching frames makes it worse and movement no longer smooth.

Comment: Thanks! I get you. So this FPS is in relation to the viewport or playback, not in relation to the actual output files in an image sequence. That makes sense. However, the dimensions themselves (Resolution, Aspect, Frame Start, Frame End) impact the output image sequence very much. Surprisingly, the FPS is bundled with these fields, but it is irrelevant for the output image sequence. I still believe, there is enough scopes for someone to get confused, and there can be a better place to keep the FPS. This may be a UI issue, but your answer helped me to understand what is going behind the scene.

Comment: But image files are, no matter what they show, just single files containing still images that have no actual connection to each other. If you rid the names of the consecutive increments Blender wouldn't know how to play them when hitting Ctrl+F11. Even if you have image0001 to image0100, but image0050 is missing, playback stops (or restarts) after image0049. On the other hand you can take 100 random images that show completely different things, if you name them image0001 to image0100, Blender will play them as a sequence when you hit Ctrl+F11 and with the FPS you've set.

Comment: Or if you take said image sequence where image0050.png is missing. Get ANY other png image, rename it to image0050.png and Blender will play the sequence up to frame 100 again, just showing that other frame on position 50. Even if the new frame has a different, maybe bigger size or aspect ratio, Blender will show it cropped to the settings. I think your confusion may arouse because of a misconception of image sequences. In the end they are timeless still images. If you look at them for the blink of an eye or an hour, they don't change. They are not animated.

Comment: Take a single image, put it in the Video Sequence Editor and set the duration to 100. Make a video with 25 fps and if you watch it, the player will show you 4 seconds of video, consisting of 100 frames. If you take a software to extract the frames of this video, you'll get 100 frames although you actually only used one image. And the dimensions impact the sequence not that much if it comes to time. If you render 100 frames at 25 fps, then render again at 60 fps, they are exactly the same. Size and ratio matter much, without you wouldn't have a picture.

Comment: But the image size or ratio here are also for preview, like the fps. Without setting the size or ratio you couldn't preview what your render camera will "see", what you will get if you render it. I guess that's the main reason why you can set a percentage there... for rendering smaller previews. If you want a final size of 960x540, why set it to 1920x1080 and 50% instead of the final dimensions directly? That's why I refer to that area more of a preview section. If you animate, you need the fps to see if it looks too slow or fast at the frame rate you're aiming for in your video.

Comment: But of course these preview settings become extremely important if you are going for the final render. You then want to render the images full size. And if you are rendering an animation to a video file directly, then the fps become important - because it's the speed that video players will use as the "normal" speed of your video. Even Blender will play a video with 25 fps at 25 fps if you hit Ctrl+F11, no matter if you've set the playback frame rate to 60 fps afterwards. And that's the difference, image sequences are ALWAYS timeless. Even after the final render you can play them at any fps.